# How to do rowSums over many columns in ``dplyr`` or ``tidyr``?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

For example, is it possible to do this in dplyr:

```
new_name <- "Sepal.Sum"
col_grep <- "Sepal"

iris <- cbind(iris, tmp_name = rowSums(iris[,grep(col_grep, names(iris))]))
names(iris)[names(iris) == "tmp_name"] <- new_name
```

This adds up all the columns that contain "Sepal" in the name and creates a new variable named "Sepal.Sum".

Importantly, the solution needs to rely on a `grep` (or `dplyr:::matches`, `dplyr:::one_of`, etc.) when selecting the columns for the `rowSums` function, and have the name of the new column be dynamic.

My application has many new columns being created in a loop, so an even better solution would use `mutate_each_` to generate many of these new columns.

Comment: Try  `iris %>% select(matches(col_grep)) %>% rowSums() %>% data.frame(.) %>% bind_cols(iris, .) %>% setNames(., c(names(iris), new_name))`

Comment: Regarding the many new columns part, based on the example code showed, it is not clear.  You were trying with `rowSums`.

Comment: Unfortunately not very elegant @akrun. And a lot slower:

``library(dplyr);
library(timeit);

new_name <- "Sepal.Sum";
col_grep <- "Sepal";

sum(timeit({
  cbind(iris, tmp_name = rowSums(iris[,grep(col_grep, names(iris))]))
  names(iris)[names(iris) == "tmp_name"] <- new_name
})$total.time);
# 0.003358779;

sum(timeit({
  iris %>% select(matches(col_grep)) %>% rowSums() %>% data.frame(.) %>% 
  bind_cols(iris, .) %>% setNames(., c(names(iris), new_name))
})$total.time);
# 0.009516129;``

Comment: I don't know about the naming part, but `iris %>% mutate(tmp_name = rowSums(.[grep(col_grep,names(.))]))` works fine...or if you want to get all fancy `iris %>% mutate(tmp_name = rowSums(.[] %>% select(matches(col_grep)) ))`

Comment: See my response as an answer @Frank. Feel free to add the one based on your comment as an answer and I'll accept it in a couple of days absent anything better.

Answer (score 9):

Here a `dplyr` solution that uses the `contains` special functions to be used inside `select`.

```
 iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Sum = iris %>% rowwise() %>% select(contains("Sepal")) %>% rowSums()) -> iris2
 head(iris2)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Sum
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa       8.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa       7.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa       7.9
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa       7.7
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa       8.6
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa       9.3
```

and here the benchmarks:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                      expr
 iris2 <- iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Sum = iris %>% rowwise() %>% select(contains("Sepal")) %>%      rowSums())
      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 1.816496 1.86304 2.132217 1.928748 2.509996 5.252626   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Didn't want to comment this as it's too long.

Not much in it in terms of timing for the solutions (expect the `data.table` solution which appearsslower) that have been proposed and none stand out as clearly more elegant.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
new_name <- "Sepal.Sum"
col_grep <- "Sepal"
# Make iris bigger
data(iris)
for(i in 1:18){
  iris <- bind_rows(iris, iris)
}
iris1 <- iris
system.time({ 
  # Base solution
  iris1 <- cbind(iris1, tmp_name = rowSums(iris1[,grep(col_grep, names(iris1))])) 
  names(iris1)[names(iris1) == "tmp_name"] <- new_name 
}) 
# 1.26

system.time({ 
  # less elegant dplyr solution
  iris %>% select(matches(col_grep)) %>% rowSums() %>% 
    data.frame(.) %>% bind_cols(iris, .) %>% setNames(., c(names(iris), new_name)) 
})
# 1.14

system.time({ 
  # bit more elegant dplyr solution
  iris %>% mutate(tmp_name = rowSums(.[] %>% select(matches(col_grep)))) %>% 
    rename_(.dots = setNames("tmp_name", new_name))
})
# 1.12

data(iris)
# Make iris bigger
for(i in 1:18){
  iris <- rbindlist(list(iris, iris))
}
system.time({
  setDT(iris)[, tmp_name := rowSums(.SD[,grep(col_grep, names(iris)), with = FALSE])]
  setnames(iris, "tmp_name", new_name)
})
# 2.39
```

Comment: Maybe also add `data(iris) ;library(data.table) setDT(iris)[, tmp_name := rowSums(.SD[,grep(col_grep, names(iris)), with = FALSE])];setnames(iris, "tmp_name", new_name)`

Comment: How can I get this to work inside a ``timeit``? It looks a lot faster than the others.

Comment: Just like you did with all the rest of them, no? If you create `iris` manually (like you do), you can skip the `data(iris)` part.

Comment: Why can't you just use `system.time`? Why are you using this package in the first place?

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks! The timeit package is a bit nicer in that it does a few replications.